# How to pattern match all classes with context bound

Tags: scala, typeclass, implicit

I have a type class and a few instances:

```
trait TC[T] { def doThings(x: T): Unit }
implicit val tcA = new TC[A] { /* ... */}
implicit val tcB = new TC[B] { /* ... */}
implicit val tcC = new TC[C] { /* ... */}
/* ... */
```

In my call site, I have input as Any, and I need to check if there is an implicit for the input actual type:

```
def process(in: Any) = in match {
  case x: A => implicitly[TC[A]].doThings(x)
  case x: B => implicitly[TC[B]].doThings(x)
  case x: C => implicitly[TC[C]].doThings(x)
  //...
}
```

This seems tedious and unnecessary, as I have to list all the classes that have this type class instance. Can I achieve this by something like:

```
def process(in: Any) = in match {
  case x: T : TC => implicitly[TC[T]].doThings(x) //This does not work
}
```

---

Edit: input is an Any (an Object from a Java library). Cannot use generic or context bound on the input.

Comment: The point of *typeclass* is that it resolves on compile-time. Since you don't know the exact type on compile type they won't help you. Using *typeclass* is probably not the best idea, in this case, you should stick with plain pattern matching or maybe check *visitor* pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ask for an implicit `TC`, `Any` won't work. As follows:

```scala
trait TC[T] { def doThings(x: T): Unit }

implicit def tcS: TC[String] = new TC[String] {
  override def doThings(x: String): Unit = println("string")
}

implicit def tcI: TC[Int] = new TC[Int] {
  override def doThings(x: Int): Unit = println("int")
}

def process[T : TC](x: T): Unit = implicitly[TC[T]].doThings(x)

process("")
process(1)
// process(4L) wont compile
```

[Try it out!](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/NkF71qY/1)

Comment: Sorry the input is an Any, because it is an output from a Java parsing library. The context bound obviously works when you can limit it on the input level.

Comment: @texasbruce Then simply don't use a Java parsing library. There is great libraries out there for parsing different data formats without loosing type safety.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do what you have mentioned in your question, you can write it as below, but if you just want to call doThings by finding an implicit instance of appropriate TC - refer João Guitana answer

```scala
object Main extends App {
  class A
  class B
  class C

  trait TC[T] { def doThings(x: T): Unit }
  implicit val tcA = new TC[A] {
    override def doThings(x: A): Unit = println("From A")
  }
  implicit val tcB = new TC[B] {
    override def doThings(x: B): Unit = println("From B")
  }
  implicit val tcC = new TC[C] {
    override def doThings(x: C): Unit = println("From C")
  }

  def process[T: ClassTag](in: T) = in match {
    case x: A => implicitly[TC[A]].doThings(x)
    case x: B => implicitly[TC[B]].doThings(x)
    case x: C => implicitly[TC[C]].doThings(x)
  }

  process(new A())
  process(new B())
  process(new C())

}
/* === Output ====
From A
From B
From C
*/
```